# Not a function shown in my case

Tags: javascript

hi i am trying to make a gallery here.
here is my html

```
<ul id="moniqueGalList">
    <li><img class="moniqueThumbs" src="img/1Thumb.jpg" data-bigImgPath="img/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img class="moniqueThumbs"  src="img/2Thumb.jpg" data-bigImgPath="img/2.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

And my JS

```
var currentThumbs=document.getElementsByClassName('moniqueThumbs');


function myFunction() {
    alert ("Hello World!");
}
currentThumbs.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

But somehow it says this error
**Uncaught TypeError: currentThumbs.addEventListener is not a function**
Please tell me where i am doing it wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`.

Access items with an index

```
var currentThumbs=document.getElementsByClassName('moniqueThumbs');


function myFunction() {
    alert ("Hello World!");
}

for(var i = 0; i < currentThumbs.length; i++){
    currentThumbs[i].addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}
```